# gnuplot png output doesn't plot dashed/dotted lines

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to plot a figure that contains both dashed and continuous lines with gnuplot v4.4 . The code is:

```
set term postscript eps enhanced color
set style line 1 linetype 1 lw 2
set style line 2 linetype 1 lw 2 linecolor rgb 'green'
set style line 3 linetype 1 lw 2 linecolor rgb 'blue'
set style line 4 linetype 4 lw 2 linecolor rgb 'red'
set style line 5 linetype 3 lw 2 linecolor rgb 'blue'

set border lw 3
set xtics font ',18'
set ytics font ',18'
set output 'roc.ps'
set key right bottom
plot 'roc_fpdock_isc_test' u 1:2 w l ls 1 title "Full optimization, test set" ,x w l ls 2 title "Random", 'roc_fpdock_isc_training' u 1:2 w l ls 3 title "Full optimization, training set", 'roc_mini_pep_sc_training' u 1:2 w l ls 4 title "Minimization only, training set", 'roc_mini_pep_sc_test' u 1:2 w l ls 5 title "Minimization only, test set"
```

Problem is , I can't plot it to png. When I change the `set term` instruction to: `set term png enhanced` I get only continuous lines. 
Any idea what went wrong?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It turns out that I can't seem to get dashed lines in the `png` terminal either (the one with the GD backend).  However, if you have the cairo terminals, you can get a png with dashed lines (assuming you pick the appropriate linetypes).

```
set term pngcairo dashed
set output "foo.png"
test
!display foo.png
!rm foo.png
```

As an aside, `test` is fantastic for inquiring what the behavior of a particular terminal will be.

Comment: If you have `pngcairo`, I'd advise you to use it.  In my experience, it makes nicer looking plots than `png` (the one with the GD backend).

Comment: Thx ! It saved some time after hitting the same strange issue with png term.

Comment: It's 2022 and the same problem still persists (gnuplot 5.4)! This answer is a real saver. And I realise `test` is really great.

Answer (score 3):

You have the dt option for dashtype in pngcairo. Legend here:

[image: Legend]

e.g

```
set style line 5 linetype 3 dt 5 lw 3 linecolor rgb 'green'
```

gives dashtype 5