# Deactivate subpixel rendering with pngcairo

Tags: gnuplot, rendering, cairo

Is anybody aware of a way to deactivate or configure (screen-dependent) subpixel rendering with the pngcairo terminal? `mono` does not change the behavior. I have to use `pngcairo` instead of `png` for dashing reasons. The detail below is from the `test` plot.

**Updated Workaround:** I didnot think about this before asking the question, but now I am using **pdfcairo** and converting it to png with **inkscape**, which yields the desired results and is acceptable for me. Still it would be interesting to know where this screen-optimized behavior of `pngcairo` is coming from and how one can influence it.

Minimal example to create such a file and detail from result below:

```
gnuplot
set term pngcairo mono
set output "test.png"
test
exit
```

[image: subpixel rendering detail 2]

Comment: Are you sure this is actually a property of the png file, as opposed to being an artifact introduced by the viewing program? If the gnuplot output file contains only grayscale pixels then those colors must be coming from some other source.

Comment: Yes, it‘s definitely present in the files (just those created by pngcairo, not by png), i am acutually editing it out with gimp for grayscale images, but this gets too tedious for more colored pictures. But this is not to say it may not depend on graphics drivers involved in rendering the image when it is created...

Comment: "set term pngcairo mono; set output 'mono.png'; test"  Open the output file mono.png in gimp.  So far as I can tell no pixels contain anything other than a grayscale (equal RGB).

Comment: That is interesting. With my system (gnuplot 5.2 patchlevel 6) it still shows the colors. Added a detail of the very result of the code you gave.

Comment: Aha. Specifically the character rendering. I wonder if this is a consequence of the recent fiasco of font breakage by harfbuzz/pango/cairo.   Story here: https://github.com/harfbuzz/harfbuzz/issues/2394

Comment: @Franz, just for curiosity... your are saying you have to use pngcairo because of dashing reasons. Although it's a different topic, but I'm wondering maybe it is possible to solve the dashing issue instead of the font subpixel rendering or going via Inkscape?

Comment: OK, I see, png terminal apparently can't have dashed lines...https://stackoverflow.com/q/12601348/7295599